# Get "Custom" Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, bricscad

I'm working with BricsCAD's .NET API and have encountered an issue while trying to access custom data associated with BlockReference objects. Typically, I retrieve standard attributes using AttributeReference with no trouble. However, I've stumbled upon a field labeled as "Angle1" that appears to be part of a "Custom" section, separate from the standard "Attributes" in the BlockReference.

Here's a snippet of my current approach for standard attributes:

```
ObjectId objId = selObj.ObjectId;
BlockReference blockRef = (BlockReference)trans.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);
AttributeCollection attCol = blockRef.AttributeCollection;

foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
{
   AttributeReference attRef = (AttributeReference)trans.GetObject(attId,OpenMode.ForRead);
   // Attribute handling logic...
}
```

Now, I need to access the "Angle1" value within the "Custom" data of the BlockReference. This field doesn't seem to be part of the AttributeCollection. Could someone guide me on how to access such custom data fields in BricsCAD using the .NET API?

Any pointers or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These 'custom' data seems to be 'dynamic properties'. You can access them from the [BlockReference.DynamicBlockReferencePropertyCollection](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_BlockReference_DynamicBlockReferencePropertyCollection) property.